# How to Query the result set of another query in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a two tables. One is the 'List' table where the primary key is DocEntry

```
          DocEntry    U_ZSS_LISTNAME            U_ZSS_STARTDATE
            17      WKLY_CC_F_06_22_2016    2016-06-22 00:00:00.000
            18      WKLY_CC_F_06_22_2016    2016-06-22 00:00:00.000
```

Another table is the stores table

```
      DocEntry    U_ZSS_STORE     U_ZSS_STORENAME
          17         01           General Warehouse
          17         02           West Cost Warehouse
          18         02           West Cost Warehouse
          18         04           Consignmentl Warehouse
```

These lists are assigned to different stores where DocEntry is the foreign key from the List table

The thing is I want a result which I can query to get all the lists assigned to a particular store 'U_ZSS_STORENAME'.

That is all the lists assigned to store  'West Cost Warehouse' in this case it would be the lists with DocEntry  '17' and '18'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple `INNER JOIN`:

```
Select  L.*
From    List        L
Join    Stores      S   On  S.DocEntry = L.DocEntry
Where   S.U_ZSS_STORENAME = 'West Cost Warehouse'
```

Another way to do this is with an `EXISTS` statement:

```
Select  *
From    List        L
Where Exists
(
    Select  *
    From    Stores  S
    Where   S.DocEntry = L.DocEntry
    And     S.U_ZSS_STORENAME = 'West Cost Warehouse'
)
```